# Can we uniquely determine a set which has a fixed number of pairs of idempotent elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, soft-question

### Background

In my school days I had Sanskrit as my $2^{\text{nd}}$ language. Consequently, I had to study portions of Paninian grammar, from where this thing originated in my head. Sanskrit has following 14 vowels a, ā, i, ī, u, ū, ṛ, ṝ, ḷ, ḹ, e, ai, o and au. Out of these the first 10 are considered 'Pure' vowels whereas the last 4 'Compound', formed by the *union* of a/ā with i/ī, u/ū. What drives me is that the same operation of *union* between the so called *like-pairs*: (a,ā), (i,ī), (u,ū), (ṛ,ṝ), results in the latter member, according to the rule:

a+a = a+ā = ā+a = ā+ā = ā, etc.

### Query

I thought if '+' be a binary operation on some set $S$, such that for every $x\in S,$ there exists a unique $y\in S:x+x=x+y=y+x=y$, is there any such set $S$ in mathematics? What is it called? I believe it has something to do with product of matrices:'+' being matrix product, and $S$ a set of matrices. One such example is the pair of matrices $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\-1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\textbf{0}_2$. What I want to know is whether such systems have been studied formally. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have given $x+x=x+y=y+x=y$ where $x+x=y$ will make it either (1) easy to figure out what $y$ to Pair with $x$ or (2) make it Degenerate to trivial Case.

When we exclude that to get $x+y=y+x=y$ , then there are lots of Cases where we have Similar Category stuff.

Eg :
Boolean Algebra where $+ = OR$ & $(x,y) = (0,1)$
Logic where $+ = \lor$ & $(x,y) = (false,true)$
Lattice networks where we have $min$ & $max$
Number theory where we have LCM & GCD
Set Theory where $+ = \cup$ & $x=\phi$ & $y=U$

When we include $x+x=y$ , it will Degenerate into trivial Case.
Eg Boolean Algebra : We will not get $0+0=1$
Eg Set theory : We will not get $\phi \cup \phi = U$ : We have to take $U=\phi$ too.

BTW : Your Matrix Pair will not work : When $x=[[a , a] ,[-a , -a]]$ , then there is no unique $y$ , & there are lots of $y$ values $y=[[b , b] ,[-b , -b]]$.
Degenerate Case is when we take 2 elements with $a=1$ & $b=0$ which is trivial.